# Latex: create html for opening in word

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I have written my master thesis in latex and got beautiful pdf. Now I want to publish it in a journal for which I need to convert it to html to convert it to word. I now that there options out there like tex4ht and htlatex, but I don't understand how to use them and none of the tutorials help.
Do I need to install a package? I am using TexStudio. I thought that htlatex is a command like pdflatex that I have to run. But it does not show up under the commands.

If htlatex is a command, do I need to install a package, if I don't have the command available? 
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you know how to use a command line? Or terminal? Basic computer stuff?

Comment: With [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.htm), a free program program for the command line (no buttons), the instructions are clear and you can convert directly from LaTeX to Word but I warn you: **any** conversion have problems. Be prepared to lost time fixing the output of  whatever conversion program.

Comment: You can import the PDF into Word. That's not perfect and `pandoc` is certainly the better option, but it's there off the shelf.

Answer (score 4):

`tex4ht` is a system for conversion from TeX to many different output formats, such as HTML, ODT or Epub. The system consists from several different programs, which are executed by a compilation script. The basic compilation script is `htlatex`, but it was superseded by [make4ht](https://ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en). The whole system is included in both major TeX distributions, TeX Live and Miktex, so you don't need to install anything.

For Word inclusion, it is best to use the ODT format, which can keep some features like footnotes. Word can handle this format, but it's support is buggy, so it is best to convert the ODT files to DOCX using LibreOffice.

The ODT format can be requested using this command:

```
make4ht -f odt filename.tex
```

It will create a `filename.odt` file, which needs to be converted do DOCX using LibreOffice. I am sure it is possible to add custom commands to TeXstudio, see it's [documentation](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a).

It is possible that you will run into some issues, because the conversion process isn't really straight-forward. It all depends on used packages, custom commands, etc.

Comment: This command is no longer working.

Comment: @BFurtado it should work. Do you get some errors?

Comment: I was using an old version. And took me some time to learn I had to install miktex to get the new version. Anyway, because I use memoir and a fancy cover, the ODT results in error and don't open. HTML worked fine, though. Thank you!

Comment: @BFurtado I can look at this isssue if you post it as a new question. these bugs can be usually fixed with some effort